# not able to authenticate a com.trilead.ssh2.Connection

Tags: java, authentication, connection, java-7

Heyy!

I am using `com.trilead.ssh2.Connection` in `java 7` to open a connection.

When testing I am opening a connection with `localhost` on port `22`:

`Connection connection = new Connection("localhost", 22);`

Then I am trying to authenticate with `authenticateWithPublicKey` method:

```
char[] key = IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream("keyLocation")).toCharArray();
boolean authenticated = connection.authenticateWithPublicKey("myUsername", key, "");
```

But it is not authenticating. I am running on a `mac sierra`, I'm wondering if that has anything to do. I am using a `dsa` pair of keys.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I could not have a work around for `dsa` pair of keys (i believe it has to do with the key size, and dsa is 1024). I created a new `rsa` pair of keys with 2048 size. Just as information I'll write the steps for successfully managing to authenticate the connection from the java code configured from my mac sierra:

I am in the `.ssh/` directory:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f 'key_name'
cat key_name.pub                # copy the public key
# add the public key to authorized_keys file
ssh-add -K key_name
ssh-add -A
ssh-add -l                      # just to check if key is added
```

and thats it, i managed to authenticate the connection.